# How to grab historic data from tradingview using websocket

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, tradingview-api

I used websocket to get price in real time.(using create_series,create_study etc).
Currently I am trying to grab historic data from tradingview chart (ex:2021-03-12 ~ 2021-04-04).
How can I do it using websocket?

Comment: If not provided apis in the site for help to do that, you need to do reverse engineering for understand how the data is received.